# 2-legged OAuth 1.0a in Objective C - ios app development

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, 2-legged

I am developing an iphone application in Objective-C and quite new in it. I just have the request URL, consumer key and secret. How can I do 2 legged authentication, could you provide me some code please. I already checked AFNetworking project and other samples but I think they are too complex for a noob like me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately using OAuth is not simple, and even a library like gtm-oauth (http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/) which has decent documentation and samples doesn't make it too easy.

I would try seeing if the service provider has their own library on github which should hopefully wrap the complexity. Otherwise gtm-oauth is a good place to start.

Comment: I have looked at the gtm-oauth documentation and cannot find how to do the 2-legged oath. Does anybody have a working source code example?